# How is the twice continuous differentiability inherited by $g$?

Tags: calculus

> Let $D$ be convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with a non empty interior on which $f$ is twice continuously differentiable. Let $\mathbf z\in\mathbb R^n$ and $C=\{t\in\mathbb R|\mathbf x+t\mathbf z\in D\}$, and let $g(t)=f(\mathbf x+t\mathbf z)$ for all $t\in C$. Note that $g$ inherits twice continuous differentiability from $f$.

How is the twice continuous differentiability inherited?

Comment: Chain rule.${}$

Comment: The function $\phi(t) = x+ tz$ is smooth (in fact affine), hence $g = f \circ \phi$ is at least as smooth as $f$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{z})=\mathbf{z}\cdot\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{z})
$$
lather, rinse, repeat.